# Is there a problem with the name of India's timezone in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timezone, iana

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India) that

> The IANA time zone database contains only one zone pertaining to India, namely *Asia/Kolkata*.

When checking the [authoritative source](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) mentioned above, the timezone assigned to India is indeed *Asia/Kolkata*.

This does not seem to be the case, however, in the timezones provided by my **Chrome** browser (Version 120):

```js
console.log(Intl.supportedValuesOf("timeZone").filter(x => x.includes('Asia/')))
```

There is no *Asia/Kolkata* but there is a *Asia/Calcutta*, the [name of Kolkata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolkata) until 2001.

Firefox reports *Asia/Kolkata*.

Is there a particular reason for this behaviour in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you the reason<sup>**1**</sup>, but can tell you both seem to work (using my own 'es-date-fiddler'-library (see [GitHub](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler/))).

Also: both Kolkata and Calcutta are listed in https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/param-view-timezone-values. And in Firefox `Asia/Calcutta` still works too.

Maybe it's something to file at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)

<sup>**1**</sup> Both of the timeZones seem to work, they are probably canonicalized in all browsers. Maybe it was a developer choice to list Kolkata in Firefox and Calcutta in Chrome. FYI: Edge reports "Asia/Calcutta" too (not surprising, since it uses the V8 engine). Idem Safari. Anyway, read more in the Tc39 [proposal-canonical-tz](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-canonical-tz?tab=readme-ov-file).

```html
<script type="module">
import $D from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler@latest/Bundle/index.esm.min.js";
const calcutta = $D({timeZone: `Asia/Calcutta`});
const kolkata = $D({timeZone: `Asia/Kolkata`});
console.log(`"Asia/Calcutta" time difference to your time zone: ${calcutta.timeDiffToHere}`);
console.log(`"Asia/Kolkata" time difference to your time zone: ${kolkata.timeDiffToHere}`);
</script>
```

Comment: FYI There are already issues open for this.  They're just not getting much attention.  See links in dup question.

Comment: I believe the standardization work that will ultimately resolve this is part of https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/806